# need explanation on why does EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION occur

Tags: memory-management, jvm, segmentation-fault, access-violation

Hi I know that this error which I'm going to show can't be fixed through code. I just want to know why and how is it caused and I also know its due to JVM trying to access address space of another program.

```
 A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x6dcd422a, pid=4024, tid=3900

 JRE version: 6.0_14-b08
 Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (14.0-b16 mixed mode windows-x86 )
 Problematic frame:
 V  [jvm.dll+0x17422a]

An error report file with more information is saved as:
C:\PServer\server\bin\hs_err_pid4024.log

If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
```

Comment: This looks like a bug in the JVM!  You should fill out a bug report. :-)  And it's probably caused by memory corruption or a bad pointer read, not an attempt to read another program's memory.

Comment: do you want to know about the background of access violations in general? Memory segmentation and so on? Or do you just want to know that this is caused by bugs?

Comment: Have you tried Java 6 update 23, there have been alot of bugs fixed since then.  Are you using any native libraries as they can trigger this type of error?

Comment: @yankee yeah i want to know more about Memory Segmentation and access violations if you got any good source please give it

Comment: You should try updating your JVM, Restarting your machine and see if this goes away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The book "modern operating systems" from Tanenbaum, which is available online here:

http://lovingod.host.sk/tanenbaum/Unix-Linux-Windows.html

Covers the topic in depth. (Chapter 4 is in Memory Management and Chapter 4.8 is on Memory segmentation). The short version:

It would be very bad if several programs on your PC could access each other's memory. Actually even within one program, even in one thread you have multiple areas of memory that must not influence one other. Usually a process has at least one memory area called the "stack" and one area called the "heap" (commonly every process has one heap + one stack per thread. There MAY be more segments, but this is implementation dependent and it does not matter for the explanation here). On the stack things like you function's arguments and your local variables are saved. On the heap are variables saved that's size and lifetime cannot be determined by the compiler at compile time (that would be in Java everything that you use the "new"-Operator on. Example:

```
public void bar(String hi, int myInt)
{
  String foo = new String("foobar");
}
```

in this example are two String objects: (referenced by "foo" and "hi"). Both these objects are on the heap (you know this, because at some point both Strings were allocated using "new". And in this example 3 values are on the stack. This would be the value of "myInt", "hi" and "foo". It is important to realize that "hi" and "foo" don't really contain Strings directly, but instead they contain some id that tells them were on the heap they can find the String. (This is not as easy to explain using java because java abstracts a lot. In C "hi" and "foo" would be a Pointer which is actually just an integer which represents the address in the heap where the actual value is stored).

You might ask yourself why there is a stack and a heap anyway. Why not put everything in the same place. Explaining that unfortunately exceeds the scope of this answer. Read the book I linked ;-). The short version is that stack and heap are differently managed and the separation is done for reasons of optimization.

The size of stack and heap are limited. (On Linux execute `ulimit -a` and you'll get a list including "data seg size" (heap) and "stack size" (yeah... stack :-)).).

The stack is something that just grows. Like an array that gets bigger and bigger if you append more and more data. Eventually you run out of space. In this case you may end up writing in the memory area that does not belong to you anymore. And that would be extremely bad. So the operating systems notices that and stops the program if that happens. On Linux you get a "Segmenation fault" and on Windows you get an "Access violation".

In other languages like in C, you need to manage your memory manually. A tiny error can easily cause you to accidentally write into some space that does not belong to you. In Java you have "automatic memory management" which means that the JVM does all this for you. You don't need to care and that takes loads from your shoulders as a developer (it usually does. I bet there are people out there who would disagree about the "loads" part ;-)). This means that it /should/ be impossible to produce segmentation faults with java. Unfortunatelly the JVM is not perfect. Sometimes it has bugs and screws up. And then you get what you got.

Comment: i wanted some info on where that bug could possibly exist in JVM

Comment: mostly garbage collector but anyways thanks for the long description :P :)

Comment: Might be worth checking if you're compressing 64 bit pointers or not i.e. UseCompressedOops, apparently it's enabled by default in Java 7+