# Explain the fatal error detected by java runtime EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION

Tags: windows, swing, java

Ive been working on my programs today and it was running fine this morning and then out of no where i received  `A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment` I then reffered to the log file it creates but I dont know how to make any of sense of the log file, could someone help explaining how to go about this error?

I am programming in eclipse using jdk 7 and I tried reinstalling it and still recieve same error.

here is the first section of the file:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x0a4d6fc1, pid=4852, tid=5072
#
# JRE version: 7.0-b147
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (21.0-b17 mixed mode, sharing windows-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# C  [delta.dll+0x26fc1]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

And here is a copy of the rest of the file: http://pastebin.com/R4gTizCQ

If you need more info let me know

Comment: This may help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4896502/need-explanation-on-why-does-exception-access-violation-occur[link]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in C:\Program Files\Delta Controls\3.33\System\delta.dll specifically in C  [delta.dll+0x26fc1]  oldddGetCount+0x12, so it is outside of Java. Most likely it is a bug in the ODBC driver you are using. Report it to the driver vendor.

Answer (score 1):

It just means that there was a core dump / crash of the JVM. You look at the logfile and see if it's due to any of ur code or not. If yes, you fix it, if not you report the bug at the given link and see if it's a known issue with fix/patch available. Or if you're using some beta version of JVM, you switch back to a stable release.

Here are a couple of things I noticed in the log:

1.
Check you're using correct OS/JVM combo.

```
OS=Windows_**NT**
OS: **Windows 7** Build 7601 Service Pack 1
```

2.
If delta.dll is your then check the problem.

```
Problematic frame:
# C  [delta.dll+0x26fc1]
```

Comment: Windows 7 is regularly identified as Windows NT 6.1, so I don't understand your first point. And the OS environment variable is set to Windows_NT by Windows 7 itself.

Comment: Aha.. didn't know that.. my dev env is Linux.. fortunately.. :). Thanks. My comment was because in the log file he posted, I saw these 2 entries and wondered if there was a 32/64 bit mixup.